# MDI-приложение

Tags: delphi

Как связать вкладки компоненты (`TabSet`, `TabControl`) с дочерним окном MDI-приложения? Так, чтобы при создании нового окна создавалась вкладка с таким же заголовком, при нажатии на вкладку появлялось соответствующее окно и при закрытии окна закрывалась соответствующая вкладка?

Answer (score 2):

1. Заведите список, сопоставляющий индексы табов с экземплярами окон.
2. Заведите метод, который будет отвечать за: создание окна, создание табы, занесение их в этот список.
3. Создавайте окна, используя этот метод.
4. На событии `onChange` проверяйте индекс текущей табы, загляните в список и вытаскивайте соответствующее окно.
5. С закрытием окон сложнее. Т.к. количество табов будет меняться, и придется пробегаться по списку и декрементить индексы таб, превышающие индекс закрытой табы.

Потом вы поймете, что вас в этом не устраивает, и перепишете все уже красиво в виде нескольких классов, реализующих небольшой оконный менеджер )

Ну и вообще TabSet не самый удобный компонент для этой задачи, лучше взять чтото поинтереснее (с настройками внешнего вида, иконками, крестиком). Да и VCLевский MDI таит в себе немало сюрпризов.

Comment: А как вызвать нужное окно, если свойство MDIChildren постоянно меняется.  помощью кокого свойства можно вызвать нужное окно?

Comment: послать ему сообщение [WM_MDIACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644911(v=vs.85).aspx)